# How to identify whether all nodes are processed.?

Tags: apache-camel

I have created a interceptor added to the context. This interceptor is getting executed for each node in the route. But i  want to identify when processing of all nodes is complete and do some action.

```
public class MyInterceptStrategy implements InterceptStrategy {

public int count = 0;

@Override
public Processor wrapProcessorInInterceptors(final CamelContext context,
        final ProcessorDefinition<?> definition, final Processor target,
        final Processor nextTarget) throws Exception {
    return new DelegateAsyncProcessor(new Processor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            count++;
            target.process(exchange);
            //if this is the last node print the message "all nodes processed" and count is "count"
            //System.out.println(count);
        }
    }) {

    };

}
```

}

UPDATE: Tried doing this to get the total count of nodes,but this returns all the nodes in all the routes and not just the nodes that are eligible for processing.

```
public int getTotalProcessors(CamelContext context) {
    int totalProcessorsCount = 0;
    for (Route r : context.getRoutes()) {
        totalProcessorsCount = totalProcessorsCount + r.getRouteContext().getRoute().getOutputs().size();
    }
    return totalProcessorsCount;
}
```

Comment: Maybe look at event notifier instead if you only want to do action at the end - http://camel.apache.org/eventnotifier-to-log-details-about-all-sent-exchanges.html - just only react on the exchange done event

Comment: I tried using EventNotifier but ExchangeCompletedEvent is fired when an exchange is complete and a new exchange is created for each end point.All the processing nodes belong to different exchanges.I want to perform some action for each node and print summary at the end.

Comment: What do you really mean? Each incoming message is routed as an unique exchange, are you talking about in flight exchanges as a total, or what really?